# Query to update one column of a table based on a column of a different table

Tags: query-performance, t-sql, sql-server-2016, query, update

I have two tables with below structure :

```
Create table Customer_info
(Customer_num  varchar(50),
 Customer_Branch  int);

Create table Customer_Transaction_Info
(Customer_num     varchar(50),
 Branch_Code      int,
 Trns_Measure_One int,
 Trns_Measure_Two int
 );
```

Sample data for each table:

```
insert into Customer_info(Customer_num , Customer_Branch)
values('A',1),
      ('B',2),
      ('C',3);

   Customer_num     Customer_Branch
------------------- ---------------
     A                      1
     B                      2
     C                      3

insert into Customer_Transaction_Info (Customer_num,Branch_Code,Trns_Measure_One,Trns_Measure_Two)
Values ('A',1,10,0),
       ('A',2,20,5),
       ('A',3,14,0),
       ('B',2,10,10),
       ('B',1,36,0),
       ('C',3,14,0),
       ('C',1,10,18);

 Customer_num    Branch_Code Trns_Measure_One Trns_Measure_Two
 --------------- ----------- ----------------  ---------------
    A               1           10               0
    A               2           20               5
    A               3           14               0
 -------------------------------------------------------------
    B               2           10               10
    B               1           36               0
 -------------------------------------------------------------
    C               3           14               0
    C               1           10               18
```

What I need to do is this:

1. For each `Customer_num` in `Customer_Transaction_Info` , `Trns_Measure_Two` must be assigned to the correct `Branch_Code` for that customer which is the one in the first table , `Customer_info`
2. For each `Customer_num` in `Customer_Transaction_Info`, `Trns_Measure_Two` must be updated to 0 for  incorrect branches.

So based on these the desired result is below:

```
 Customer_num    Branch_Code Trns_Measure_One Trns_Measure_Two
 --------------- ----------- ----------------  ---------------
    A               1           10               0---> Update to 5
    A               2           20               5---> Update to 0
    A               3           14               0
 -------------------------------------------------------------
    B               2           10               10---> This record is Correct
    B               1           36               0
 -------------------------------------------------------------
    C               3           14               0 ---> Update to 18
    C               1           10               18---> Update to 0
```

We must take these facts into consideration that:

1. There's only one `Customer_Branch` for each `Customer_num` in `Customer_info` table.
2. There's only one non-zero `Trns_Measure_Two` for each `Customer_num` in `Customer_Transaction_Info`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE Customer_Transaction_Info
SET Trns_Measure_Two = subquery.Trns_Measure_Two
FROM (SELECT cti.Customer_num, cti.Branch_Code, cti.Trns_Measure_One,
             CASE WHEN ci.Customer_Branch = cti.Branch_Code
                  THEN MAX(cti.Trns_Measure_Two) OVER (PARTITION BY cti.Customer_num)
                  ELSE 0
                  END Trns_Measure_Two
      FROM Customer_info ci
      JOIN Customer_Transaction_Info cti ON ci.Customer_num = cti.Customer_num) subquery
WHERE Customer_Transaction_Info.Customer_num = subquery.Customer_num
  AND Customer_Transaction_Info.Branch_Code = subquery.Branch_Code
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5153b26c1fdb612b95a898d20b01e6d1)

Comment: Thanks . which one is better in terms of performance? Mine or yours?I think yours cause you have only one join in your query

Comment: @Pantea I cannot say... this is highly depends on data statistic, precise DDLs and many other factors. The amount of joins itself means nothing, try to compare execution plans. Practice may give the answer - it is the best tester.

Comment: @Pantea Remember - my query assumes that `Trns_Measure_Two` cannot be negative.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve the first requirement:

```
UPDATE CTI.Trns_Measure_Two -- Updating Customer_info.Trns_Measure_Two
SET CTI.Trns_Measure_Two = CTI2.Trns_Measure_Two -- Set it to the correct value (the only non-zero value for that Customer_num)
FROM Customer_Transaction_Info AS CTI
INNER JOIN Customer_info AS CI -- Inner joining Customer_info to ensure we only update for the correct Customer and Branch
    ON CTI.Customer_num = CI.Customer_num
    AND CTI.Branch_Code = CI.Customer_Branch
INNER JOIN Customer_Transaction_Info AS CTI2 -- Need to re-join to Customer_Transaction_Info on Customer_num and Trns_Measure_Two <> 0 to get this customer's non-zero correct value
    ON CTI.Customer_num = CTI2.Customer_num
    AND CTI2.Trns_Measure_Two <> 0
```

This should update the incorrect branches for your second requirement:

```
UPDATE CTI.Trns_Measure_Two -- Updating Customer_info.Trns_Measure_Two
SET CTI.Trns_Measure_Two = 0 -- Setting incorrect values to 0
FROM Customer_Transaction_Info AS CTI
LEFT JOIN Customer_info AS CI -- Left joining to Customer_info so we can see where there's no match by Customer_num and Customer_Branch
    ON CTI.Customer_num = CI.Customer_num
    AND CTI.Branch_Code = CI.Customer_Branch
WHERE CI.Customer_num IS NULL -- This filters Customer_Transaction_Info to only the bad records (where there's no match to Customer_info)
```

Please see the comments for information on how these two update statements work.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this with only one update statement.

Comment: No problem! The above is achievable in one update statement as well, but I didn't see that as part of your request so I kept them as two separate statements (figured it was a little clearer to read).

Comment: Thanks.I first solved it with two separate update too but reached the solution just now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
update a
set a.Trns_Measure_Two = case
                            when b.Trns_Measure_Two is null then 0
                            else b.Trns_Measure_Two end
  from Customer_Transaction_Info a
  left join (select t1.Customer_num, t1.Customer_Branch, t2.Trns_Measure_Two
               from Customer_info t1
              inner join (select distinct i.Customer_num, i.Trns_Measure_Two
                           from Customer_Transaction_Info i
                          where i.Trns_Measure_Two > 0) t2
                 on t1.Customer_num = t2.Customer_num) b
    on a.Customer_num = b.Customer_num
   and a.Branch_Code = b.Customer_Branch;
```